# Can suspended users still ask and answer questions?

Tags: support, account-suspension

As part of our [sekkrit discussions](http://so.mrozekma.com/secret-meta.png) between moderators I asked to be suspended on a site to see if suspended users can edit their profile. (Hint: they cannot.)

However, while suspended, I noticed that all question pages still had the "Answer question" box. Also, the "Ask question" page didn't return a 404 like the edit account page did, but loaded normally:

[image]

Unfortunately I was unsuspended before I could find out. Sure, I could suspend myself on Gaming, but SE treats suspended moderators... weirdly, as you might have guessed :)

At any rate — is this by design? Can suspended users still ask and answer questions? Or do they get blocked only on submission? (I'd consider that a bug.)

Comment: This [has been discussed before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91636/hide-ask-question-button-and-answer-section), specifically making the UI more intuitive for suspended users by disabling/hiding functionality that they don't have the privileges to use. Unfortunately, that question has now been deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They get blocked on submission.

If you don't like that, well, *don't get suspended*. Problem solved.

Comment: I understand UX for suspended users isn't much of a concern for you. YOU MONSTERS! ___THINK OF THE TROUBLEMAKERS!!!!!!!___